# How does jupyter notebook import plotly.js for rendering?

Tags: javascript, python, jupyter-notebook

I can see that in the cell code of a rendered plotly chart I have:

```
<div>
<div id=\"8db95fda-d2ee-4280-be5c-d420530be3bc\" class=\"plotly-graph-div\" style=\"height:525px; width:100%;\"></div>
<script type=\"text/javascript\">

<!-- NOTE THIS LINE: -->
require([\"plotly\"], function(Plotly) ...
```

I am assuming `require` is require.js which would be bundled with jupyter, but how does it install plotly.js?

Running that locally with require.js installed, I get the error:

```
r.js:168 Uncaught Error: Script error for "plotly"
https://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at makeError (r.js:168:17)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (r.js:1738:36)
```

*(r.js being my require.js local file)*

I expect this error as it's not loaded locally, but just tried it for the heck of it. Assuming if require.js is being used, then plotly.js is being loaded as well.

But perhaps it's not require.js

I've looked at the code pulled from pypi on the `plotly` package and I don't see any JS files in there. How does it originally pull in the plotly package (and other HTML rendered packages)?